# Create Simple Controller Not Working In my module

Tags: module, third-party-module

I am Trying To create a Simple Module. It's Found 404 page Error.

My config file in app/etc/module/dixit_featured.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <config>
          <modules>
             <dixit_featured>
                <active>true</active>
                <codepool>local</codepool>
              </dixit_featured>
          </modules>
         </config>
```

Create Controllrer in app\code\local\dixit\featured\controllers\IndexController.php

```
    <?php
      class dixit_featured_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
       {
           public function indexAction ()
           {
            echo 'test index';
           }
           public function mamethodeAction ()
           {
            echo 'test mymethod';
            }
        }
     ?>
```

And Create My Plugin xml file in app\code\local\dixit\featured\etc\config.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <config>
            <modules>
               <dixit_featured>
                  <version>1.0.1</version>
               </dixit_featured>
             </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
             <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>dixit_featured</module>
                    <frontname>dixit</frontname>
                </args>
             <mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
  </config>
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should do is write the names (namespace, module and class names) in correct case (camelcase)

`app/etc/module/dixit_featured.xml` should be `app/etc/module/Dixit_Featured.xml`

Inside this file and module's configuration file (etc/config.xml) you should also use the correct case for the namespace and module name

```
<modules>
  <Dixit_Featured>
    <active>true</active>
    <codepool>local</codepool>
  </Dixit_Featured>
</modules>
```

Your namespace and module folders should also be camelcase

`app\code\local\dixit\featured` should be changed to `app\code\local\Dixit\Featured`

And finally, use correct case in class names:
`class Dixit_Featured_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`

Answer (score 0):

there are lot of issue in your Module>Please check

My config file in `app/etc/module/dixit_featured.xml`
Path should be `Dixit_Featured.xml`  from

```
dixit_featured.xml
```

and code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
     <Dixit_Featured> <!--  Dixit_Featured from  dixit_featured -->
    <active>true</active>
    <codepool>local</codepool>
      </Dixit_Featured> <!--  Dixit_Featured from dixit_featured -->
  </modules>
 </config>
```

Created `Controllrer` in `app\code\local\dixit\featured\controllers\IndexController.php`
Path should be `app\code\local\Dixit\Featured\controllers\IndexController.`php

```
<?php
class Dixit_Featured_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction ()
   {
    echo 'test index';
   }
   public function mamethodeAction ()
   {
    echo 'test mymethod';
    }
}
?>
```

Class Should be  `dixit_featured_IndexController` from  `Dixit_Featured_IndexController`

And Created My Plugin xml file in `app\code\local\dixit\featured\etc\config.xml`
to 
change   xml file in `app\code\local\Dixit\Featured\etc\config.xml` and look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
       <dixit_featured><!--  Dixit_Featured from dixit_featured -->
      <version>1.0.1</version>
       </dixit_featured> <!--  Dixit_Featured from dixit_featured -->
     </modules>
<frontend>
<routers>
     <mymodule>
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
        <module>Dixit_Featured</module> <!--  Dixit_Featured to  dixit_featured -->
        <frontname>dixit</frontname>
    </args>
     <mymodule>
</routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Please study basic study of [module](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)